# when I output p1.y I should get output 201 as per my understanding as y is stored in prototype of person. why am I getting 200?

Tags: javascript

```js
function person(){ 
  this.x = 100;
} 
person.prototype.y = 200; 

var p1 = new person(); 
var p2 = new person();

++p1.y;

console.log(p1.y);
console.log(p2.y);
```

when I output p2.y I should get output 201 as per my understanding as y is stored in prototype of person. why am I getting 200 ?

Answer (score 2):

> y is stored in prototype of person

Not exactly. Assigning a property, like `++p1.y` does (`p1.y = p1.y + 1`), creates an own property on the object `p1`. The `person.prototype.y` property keeps the value `200`. You would need to do

```
++person.prototype.y;
```

to update the property that both instances inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

`Prototype` properties are shared between instances but only if the are passed by reference (eg methods or other objects). A `number` is passed by value thus copied in each instance. 
When you increase the `++p1.y` the similar property of `p2` is NOT affected. 
Consider the following example where we have a number property in the prototype and an object property in the prototype (passed by reference, thus NOT copied)

```
function person(){ 

  this.x = 100;
} 
person.prototype.y = 200; // passed by value
person.prototype.obj = {};  // object passed by reference

var p1 = new person(); 
var p2 = new person();

++p1.y;
p1.obj.avalue = 10

console.log(p1.y);
console.log(p2.y);

console.log(p1.obj);
console.log(p2.obj);
```

The above will output sth like the following (try it your self):

```
201
200
{ avalue: 10 }
{ avalue: 10 }
```

Comment: "*copied at instantiation of object*" - no, it's not. It's dynamically inherited.

Comment: @Bergi, what is the difference, i think we are talking about the same thing. The important here is that it is passed by value, thus copied. That is why it is not affected

Comment: @Bergi, edited the answer, would you care to change your vote?

Comment: There is no passing around, there is no copying. The value isn't touched at the instantiation of the object. There aren't multiple values, there is only one - on the prototype.

Comment: The number value is passed by value in the prototype, the object property is passed by reference. This explains the difference between the two. If you want to call it "copying" or sth else is not big issue. passed by value is waht is important

Comment: Even if you remove the claim that something happens to the primitive value at instantiation, the answer is still wrong - the OPs problem has nothing to do with objects being reference values. It's all about the assignment to `p1.y`.

Comment: It explains the confusion the OP is having about increasing the value in one instance and expecting it to affect the other instance as well. This is the explanation. Anyway, do as you please.

Comment: I can do `p1.y = {}`. Or `p1.obj = {aValue: 10};`. Neither of them affects the other instance. It has nothing to do with them being objects.

Comment: No in the first case you add a custom property to the `p1` instance directly (not the prototype) and in the second case you change the reference object completely. Anyway in javascript the way to pass by reference is to wrap inside an object reference. This is known in javascript this is not C nor php

Comment: "*you add a custom property to the p1 instance directly (not the prototype)*" - Yes, and that's exactly what happens in the OPs code as well, just with a primitive value.

Comment: Exactly, primitive values are passed by value, not reference. I dont know why we are disagreeing here. The way to pass by reference in javascript is to wrap inside an object (which is passed by reference)